# Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64')

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to predict ticket sales and receive the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('<M8[ns]') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

I attached here my code. The error seems to occur when running `pred_lr = linear_reg.predict(X_all)`. I assume I have to change the type somewhere? But I couldn't figure out what I do actually wrong.

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

    # Load data
    event_data = pd.read_csv('event_data.csv')

    # Explore data
    data = pd.DataFrame(event_data)

    split_date = pd.datetime(2019,3,31)
    data['created'] = pd.to_datetime(data['created'])

    data_train = data[data.created < split_date]
    data_test = data[data.created >= split_date]

    # predict prices based on date
    X_train = data_train.created[:, np.newaxis]
    y_train = data_train.tickets_sold

    linear_reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

    # predict on all data
    X_all = event_data.created[:, np.newaxis]

    pred_lr = linear_reg.predict(X_all)
```

All rows [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1usJe6baWA2kEUa_g4JSHbF9bYlaM5NeRtWCoMGTh-ww/edit#gid=0). Here the head of my data.

```
created event_id tickets_sold tickets_sold_sum
0   3/12/19 1   90  90
1   3/13/19 1   40  130
2   3/14/19 1   13  143
3   3/15/19 1   8   151
4   3/16/19 1   13  164
```

Comment: Arguably the issue derives from the type of `event_data.created`. Please, provide an excerpt of it (not an image), in order to make the error reproducible.

Comment: Hi @sentence I changed it and added an excerpt.

Comment: Are you sure the error is on `linear_reg.predict(X_all)` and not during `linear_reg = LinearRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)`? Post the complete stack trace
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with `datetime` values is to convert them into `POSIX timestamps`.

```
X_train = data_train.created.astype("int64").values.reshape(-1, 1) // 10**9
```

and

```
X_all = event_data.created.astype("int64").values.reshape(-1, 1) // 10**9
```

However this way you are going to learn almost nothing useful to predict data in the future, since POSIX time values for the test set are reasonably outside of the range of POSIX time values in the training set.

My suggestion is to modify `X_train` and `X_all` so as to get from the date multiple informative features (as categorical features using a one-hot encoding):

1. day of the week
2. day of the month
3. month of the year
4. year

Comment: That seems to work! Could you explain to me what the problem was there? What are you doing with `values.reshape(-1, 1). My prediction still seems to be wrong and goes into minus. But I think that's another problem.

Comment: Added explanation and suggestion.